# Android - Difference between Gridlayout and Staggered Gridlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout, staggeredgridlayout

I am working in android material design api & want to display some data in grid format. I tried both `GridLayout` and `StaggeredGridlayout` and both look same. For general information, i want to ask **what is the difference between `Gridlayout` and `StaggeredGridlayout`?**

Thank you.

Comment: gridview is symmetric and staggered gridview is asymmetric..

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Grid View** : It is is a `ViewGroup` that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. In this each ***Grid is of same size (Height and width).*** Grid View shows symmetric items in view.

[image: Grid View]

**Staggered Grid View** : It is basically an extension to `Grid View` but in this each ***Grid is of varying size(Height and width)***. Staggered Grid View shows asymmetric items in view.

[image: staggered grid view]

Tutorial to implement Staggered Grid View :

1. [Staggered Grid View](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/)
2. [Pinterest Masonry layout Staggered Grid View](http://blog.grafixartist.com/pinterest-masonry-layout-staggered-grid/)

Answer (score 8):

My time at Oodles Technologies taught me about staggered.
I'll share that.

**StaggeredGridLayout** is a LayoutManager, it is just like a GridView but in this grid each view have its own size (height and width). It supports both vertical and horizontal layouts.

Below are some basic steps to create a staggered grid:

**1) Create a view.**

As we know StaggeredGrid is not a direct view, it is a LayoutManager that lays out children in a staggered grid formation. We use RecyclerView as a view for the staggerd grid.
Here is our RecyclerView in layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/favPlaces"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**2) Set StaggeredGridLayout LayoutManager.**

Once our view is ready, let's use LayoutManager to create grids on the view:

```java
RecyclerView favPlaces = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.favPlaces);
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
favPlaces.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
favPlaces.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

**3) Adapter to inflate the StaggeredGrid views.**

To inflate the data in form of a grid, we first need a layout which will represent that data. We are using CardView for this and the layout is:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardcornerradius="4dp"
        app:cardusecompatpadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/placePic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustviewbounds="true"
                android:scaletype="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textsize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

After we setup our all the basic steps, it's time to complete our main activity. Here is the complete code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    int placeImage[]= {R.drawable.agattia_airport_lakshadweep,R.drawable.nainital,R.drawable.goa,
            R.drawable.lotus_temple,R.drawable.valley_of_flowers,R.drawable.ranikhet,R.drawable.dehradun,R.drawable.nainital1};
 
    String placeName[]= {"Lakshadweep, India","Nainital, India","Goa, India","Lotus-Temple, India","Valley-Of-Flowers, India","Ranikhet, India",
    "Dehradun, India","Nainital, India"};
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView favPlaces = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.favPlaces);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        favPlaces.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        favPlaces.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<PlaceDetails> placeList = getPlaces();
 
        StaggeredAdapter staggeredAdapter = new StaggeredAdapter(placeList);
        favPlaces.setAdapter(staggeredAdapter);
    }
 
    private ArrayList<PlaceDetails> getPlaces() {
        ArrayList<PlaceDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index=0; index<placeImage.length;index++){
            details.add(new PlaceDetails(placeImage[index],placeName[index]));
        }
        return details;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**StaggeredGridlayout**

1. This lays out children in a staggered grid formation.
2. It supports horizontal & vertical layout as well as an ability to layout children in reverse.
3. Staggered grids are likely to have gaps at the edges of the layout.
4. To avoid the gaps, `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` can offset spans independently or move items between spans. You can control this behavior via `setGapStrategy(int)`.

[image]

**GridLayout**

1. This lays out its children in a rectangular grid.
2. The grid is composed of a set of infinitely thin lines that separate the viewing area into cells.
3. Children occupy one or more contiguous cells, as defined by their `rowSpec` and `columnSpec` layout parameters.

[image: Example of GridLayout]

Comment: your image is not StaggeredGridLayout , it's custom GridLayout from https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Comment: @javaacm it doesn't really matter as he's clarifying his point correctly...

Answer (score 0):

A **staggered grid Layout** includes multiple columns with multiple rows of varying sizes.

It allows for a flexible column/row view with a header and footer and looks fairly easy to implement, though Gradle users will have an easier time than those working with Eclipse and Ant. This is what the view looks like in the [Etsy Github app](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) for which it was developed.

Whereas a [**GridLayout**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) is a layout that places its children in a rectangular grid.

It was introduced in API level 14, and was recently backported in the Support Library. Its main purpose is to solve alignment and performance problems in other layouts. Check out [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) if you want to learn more about GridLayout.